# VBA MS Word: Trigger event when text changes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to trigger an event as soon as the text in the (active) document changes. As I understand it, `WindowSelectionChange` is most suitable for this. Is this indeed the case? If so, how exactly can I use it? I've read the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff821218.aspx) but I can't get my head around it, especially about which code goes in which file. Right now, I've all my code in the default module file in the "Modules" folder in the project.

FYI: I'm not really typing in the document, instead I only do Ctr+A, to select the existing content, and Ctrl+V, to replace it by new content. At that moment, I want the event to be triggered.

Comment: No `WindowSelectionChange` is not suitable for this as it will trigger whenever `Selection` is changed and that could be very annoying. AFAIK and I could be wrong but there is not other event which can trap text changes in MS Word. BTW Do you want to trap the key combination `CTL V` or `Pasting` in general? If it is the `Paste` event then you might want to see this? http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/catchpaste.asp

Comment: It seems from the link there's isn't really a generic paste event but rather a click and key event. In any case, the `Application.OnKey` doesn't seem to work for Word. To me it doesn't really matter how the event is triggered, as long as `Ctrl+V` both pasts the text and calls the Macro. Until now, I haven't been able to make it work :(

Answer (score 4):

Although I wasn't able to find a solution for my specific question, I did find something that gave me results I wanted:

```
Sub EditPaste()

    Selection.Paste
    'Other code

End Sub
```

It's not quite the same as a 'text changed' event, but for me  it is, because I only change the text by pasting new text. Because I named the Sub the same way as the `actual` paste event, this Sub is called whenever I paste something. Then, it's only a matter of adding the actual paste operation and then add your own code.

In short: instead of creating an event for an operation it's much easier to redefine the operation.